# Delete last node in linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list

I am implementing deletion of last node in linked list using Python. Below is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.next = None
        
def printList(head):
    curr = head
    while curr != None:
        print(curr.key, end=" ")
        curr = curr.next
    
def deleteLastNode(head):
    if head == None:
        return None
    
    temp = head
    
    # Iterating till the last Node
    while temp.next != None:
        temp = temp.next
    temp = None
    return head

# Driver code
head = Node(10)
head.next = Node(20)
head.next.next = Node(30)

head = deleteLastNode(head)
printList(head)
```

However, in output I'm still getting the complete linked list.

```
10 20 30
```

How is it printing `30` when the last node is already set to `temp = None`?

Comment: `temp = None` means you assign `None` to `temp`, it doesn't mean `prev.next = None`. Also, the stop condition of while loop is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your linked list is:

```
10 -> 20 -> 30

^head
```

Your iteration:

```
10 -> 20 -> 30

^head       ^temp
```

Then when you do `temp = None`, just means(you just assign `None` to `temp`):

```
10 -> 20 -> 30       None

^head                ^temp
```

A correct way is when you iterate on `20`, do `temp.next = None` to remove the reference to the last node. So your code might be:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.next = None
        
def printList(head):
    curr = head
    while curr != None:
        print(curr.key, end=" ")
        curr = curr.next
    
def deleteLastNode(head):
    if head == None:
        return None
    
    temp = head
    
    # Iterating till the last Node
    while temp.next.next != None:
        temp = temp.next
    temp.next = None
    return head

# Driver code
head = Node(10)
head.next = Node(20)
head.next.next = Node(30)

head = deleteLastNode(head)
printList(head)
```

This code would work when your linked list contain at least two elements. When there is only one element, this will raise exception. I would recommend you use a dummy head node which `next` point to the real head node.

Comment: @Avinash Just accept it if this really work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#Another way of solving 
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.next = None
    
def printList(head):
    curr = head
    while curr != None:
        print(curr.key, end=" ")
        curr = curr.next

def deleteLastNode(head):
    if head == None:
        return None

    temp = head
    prev=None    #creating the value of previous element
    # Iterating till the last Node
    while temp.next != None:
        prev=temp  #updating for every iteration
        temp = temp.next
    prev.next = None #returning as NONE value
    return head

# Driver code
head = Node(10)
head.next = Node(20)
head.next.next = Node(30)

head = deleteLastNode(head)
printList(head)
```